# Default credential for git-credential-manager in Windows

Tags: windows, git, windows-subsystem-for-linux, git-credential-manager

I'm using git-credential-manager on Windows (I'm working in WSL through VSCode and natively on windows with Visual Studio for .NET stuff) . I have a GPG key I use to sign commits and I'm authenticating via HTTPS to GitHub. I'm only need one credential on this machine, but it somehow likes to randomly create duplicates and I want to understand what I need to configure to force git to always use the same credential.

For example Visual Studio insists on making it's own credential every time I use it (maybe because I log in VS via GitHub?) but I want it to use the same one used by VSCode if it's already present in Credential Manager. From what I understand, credentials sit in windows and can be shared with WSL, so this should be possible?

Basically I'm looking for a way to mark one credential as 'default' and be explicit if I ever want to use a different one

I'd like everything on this machine to call GitHub with the same credential